# Does editing to replace "reputation" and "rep" with "reputation points" make sense?

Tags: discussion, edits

Recently, somebody made [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/290074/2) edit to one of my questions. Their edit summary states:

> Copy edited. Used the official name of Stack Overflow - see section "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name" in https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance (the last section).

In my opinion, the edit harms readability, I would've been okay with replacing "rep" with "reputation", but to me reading "reputation points" everywhere "reputation" fits seems choppy.

I don't want to blindly revert the edit, however, so I figure I'll ask everyone's opinion on it.

Comment: Not everybody knows that "rep" means "reputation points". Someone new to Stack Exchange probably won't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ale, note that I said specifically "I would've been okay with replacing "rep" with "reputation:

Comment: You have been *Mortensen'd*. He is one of the top most editors across the whole network. See his [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen?tab=activity&sort=revisions). It is an honor if your post gets touched by him. You can always @ping him under your post if you have doubts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that adding "points" is a bit redundant, I'm not sure it actually harms readability though. I would reject a *suggested* edit that only changed "rep" to "reputation", with or without "points". It doesn't improve anything and is a waste of everyone's time. The user in question can edit without peer-review though, so there was no suggestion and no review.

More importantly; the edit *did* correct "StackOverflow" to "Stack Overflow", which – as the edit summary stated – is the correct name. I do this too and IMO makes the edit worthwhile.

If you really have a problem with the "reputation points" changes, go back and change them.  The "Stack Overflow" change should stay though.